# Mysql won't start server during installation

Tags: mysql

I am trying to install mysql5.54 on windows 10 (1909) on a computer. Using Mysql latest installer.
Using port 3308

I have two issues:

1: I have to uncheck "Server data file" to complete install. (If I leave it checked, it always tells me it failed during installation)

2. During "Apply configuration", it stops in "Starting the server" for ever.

Can someone tell me how to trace the problem? I've installed this for many times, never had this problem previously.

I have mysql 5.7 installed on another port 3306, I don't think this will be the case.

I tried to run mysql.exe cmd line, it said:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

why it is denied my root user?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

you should consider using docker or a vm, running two sql server on one computer can cause trouble obviously.

But i think you should choose only a different path for your second server
 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installer/en/mysql-installer-change-path-proc.html

So mysql can use it to store its cnf/ini filr an use a different data folder

Comment: Running two mysql on a computer should not a problem if you configure it properly. And I am using different path.

Comment: I installed it on a server with mysql 8.0.19 and it run with out a problem 5.5,62 . Are you using another version? And the installation was as far as i can see the same as ever root user selecting Port and name for the server and named pies.